# PHP displaying Text using line break

Tags: php, sql, line, multiline, break

I used

```
<textarea name="question" class="input" width="250"></textarea>
```

to add data in sql. i used multi line , in database also data is stored in multi line only.

Then i used

```
$question=$row['1'];
echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>",$row[1],"</td></tr>
```

to display the data but the data are displaying in single line . how to make it appear in mulit line like as in database.

Comment: wrap the text in `<pre>` tags

Comment: ``<?php echo(nl2br($row[1])); ?>``

Comment: or use nl2br(), but not in the textarea

Comment: @VainFellowman regarding code he wants to display it in a table cell - so ``nl2br()`` should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>",$row[1],"</td></tr>
```

To

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>".nl2br($row[1])."</td></tr>";
```

Comment: user <pre> tag or try nl2br()

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert the newlines to HTML line breaks. Try PHP's `nl2br`:

```
echo "<tr><td colspan='5'>".nl2br($row[1])."</td></tr>
```

Comment: `nl2br($row[1], /*is_xhtml*/ false)`, HTML 4 does not allow closing slash `<br />`.